# CAN bus with 3 nodes problem

Tags: arduino, esp32, can

I am testing a CAN bus network with 3 nodes. What I mean by node is a esp32 which has a CAN controller and a tja1051 transceiver module. There seems to be no problem when here are just two nodes but when I connect my 3rd node to transmit a message with the other 2 set up to just receive it does not work.

For context I am using sandeepmistry CAN library on the arduino IDE, and I can only monitor two esp32s at a time. I am doing all of this on a breadboard(s) so it is possible there is a connection issue, but I have probably spent a good hour in total making sure everything is in the right place. One source of error that I recognize is that I am using 100 ohm resistors instead of 120 ohms but I have read that it is fine to use no resistors? I am powering one of the esp32 with the 3v3 pin (since I can only power 2 at a time) and all the grounds are common. Additionally I am pretty sure that there is no problem with the transceiver modules, I have swapped them around and it seems to work with just 2 nodes.
I am using the code provided in the following link https://www.circuitstate.com/tutorials/what-is-can-bus-how-to-use-can-interface-with-esp32-and-arduino/
It is very similar to the example code provided by sandeepmistry. Currently when I want to make a node transmit messages or receive messages I use canSender() or canReceiver() functions in the loop.

Oddly when I monitor two of the esp32s I can see that the 3rd node seemingly manages to send messages but when the code on the other esp32 I am monitoring loads, the 3rd node just stops working (the CAN.write(...) program lines dont run).

I would greatly appreciate any help reducing the possible sources of error.

Edit: I went back to using only 2 nodes and the problem persisted. I believe the problem is the 3rd esp32 because when I switch esp32 (using the same transceiver) it miraculously works. I have messed around using different pins for rx and tx using CAN.setPins() and nothing works.

Comment: Are the termination resistor on the modules or separate terminations on bus?

Comment: I have a small breadboard dedicated for the 2 termination resistors, not using the module resistors (I have made sure)

Comment: Are you using 3 unique ID addresses?

Comment: @Andyaka what addresses ?!

Comment: _"I have read that it is fine to use no resistors?"_ Definitely not fine to use no terminating resistors. Btw, [AN96116](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN96116.pdf) recommends a minimum termination resistance of 118Ω (I don't think that's the issue tho).

Comment: @Andyaka I am only using one node to send a message out of 3 so I dont think the unique ID is the problem or am I missing something?

Comment: @Velvet there are no "node IDs" in CAN!

Comment: @Velvet  Even message IDs don't have to be unique, different nodes can send messages with same ID with careful time management or custom round-robin protocol on top. CAN is specifically _designed_ to handle collisions, it is not a "must" to avoid them, only "nice to have".

Comment: Do you have access to the CAN status register and REC/TEC values?

Comment: @Velvet I have no idea how to access them (I am using the arduino IDE). It looks like the sandeepmistry CAN library does not have this feature https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-CAN/blob/master/API.md

Comment: @Velvet please correct me if I am wrong but I do not think that the MCP2515.h library will work since I am using the ESP32 inbuilt CAN controller instead of a MCP2515 chip

Comment: This could be caused by anything. You need to listen on the CAN traffic and see if there are error frames, before anything else. That could in turn be caused by numerous other issues.

Comment: As for MCP2515, professionals stopped using that one 20 years ago. Unless you have very specialized requirements.

Comment: I agree with @Lundin. Not enough data to even begin to guess. The schematics with 2 and 3 nodes would help. The specific messages that you are sending would help. Are there nodes sending simultaneously by mistake or by design? Are you transmitting in a loop with no pauses or checking for success in between? Is there auto-retransmit function in ESP and if yes do you enable it? Do you handle error frames in your code in any way? Do you check status (like bus-off) in your code? Even basics, like bitrate and corresponding quanta configuration may be useful.

Comment: @Maple the code I am using is provided in the post, you just need to scroll down to the code section (I probably should have formatted my post to be more neat though to be fair). The transmitting node should be sending a message in a loop and it waits 1 second after sending one. The bit rate of all the nodes are 500kbs. I will use the library suggested by Velvet tomorrow to get more information

Comment: @Velvel i am unable to use CAN.readRegister(REG_RXERR), I get a compiler error saying that REG_RXERR is not defined in this scope. I have looked at the ESP32 technical document and it seems that there is no such register.

Comment: Just to be clear, I didn't suggest to use that library. In a comment above you've mentioned said library, so I thought that was what you were using. If that's not the case, all my other comments are obsolete. In any case, there *must* be some way to read CAN_STATUS, CAN_REC and CAN_TEC. These registers will most likely help you narrow the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in fact with the 3rd esp32, a Duinotech esp32 wroom 32. Not sure if it is a problem with the manufacturer or if I simply got unlucky. I replaced the esp32 and it works fine now.